# Change the line height of the selected text with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, editor, wysiwyg

I am trying to program my own WYSIWYG editor as a summer project. I am trying to implement the line height function that controls(single spacing, double spacing, etc). I have created the dropdown that will allow users to select between the types of spacing. However, I cannot seem to get the right Javascript, because the selected text does not change in line spacing at all no matter which option I choose. Can someone please take a look at my Javascript and tell me where I went wrong? If possible, can you give me the correct code for the Javascript so I can refer off of it? Thank you!

HTML(working):

```
 <select id="lineHeight" onchange="spacing(this)">
                                <option value="20px">20px</option>
                                <option value="80px">80px</option>
                                <option value="100px">100px</option>
                                <option value="200px">200px</option>
                            </select>
```

Javascript(not working)

```
function spacing(sel) {
        var text = editor.document.getSelection();
        text.style.lineHeight = sel.value;
    }
```

Comment: "line-height=10px" should be "line-height:10px".  Where is your getSelection() coming from? I can't find a reference to it.

Comment: I suggest you grab your code and prove your point into a code snippet. As there are a few things missing as what html element has the #textcontent class. We don't know if it is an *inline*  display element. If it is not *inline* the line-height wouldn't have any effect.

Comment: getSelection() returns the text that I have highlighted on the screen. I believe this method works correctly, because I tested by alerting me when I selected some text.

Comment: I apologize. the #textcontent was not supposed to be there. So I do not have any CSS for this dropdown. Therefore, the only two code relevant are the HTML and Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, perhaps this will work for you:

```js
function changeStyle( property, value ) {
    if ( window.getSelection().rangeCount ) {
        var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt( 0 ),
            contents = range.extractContents(),
            span = document.createElement( 'span' );

        span.style[ property ] = value;
        span.appendChild( contents );
        range.insertNode( span );
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
    }
}
```

```css
#editor {
    width: 350px;
    max-height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid #ddd
}
```

```html
<p>
    <label for="lineHeight">Line Height: </label>
    <select id="lineHeight" onchange="changeStyle('line-height', this.value)">
        <option value="20px">20px</option>
        <option value="80px">80px</option>
        <option value="100px">100px</option>
        <option value="200px">200px</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="changeStyle('font-weight', 'bold')">Bold</button>
    <button onclick="changeStyle('font-style', 'italic')">Italic</button>
    <button onclick="changeStyle('color', 'red')">Color</button>
    <button onclick="changeStyle('background-color', 'yellow')">Background</button>
</p>

<div id="editor" contenteditable>Change the line height of the selected text with Javascript:<br>Please note that this example should be completed.</div>
```